# customized paypal buy now button

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to build a customized paypal "buy now" button/link. The button shall be generated automatically and be customized for each user of my web-page with the users' email address. The email address is taken out of a database and the button/link is generated automatically by my PHP script and an email that contains the customized link is sent to the user. When the user now clicks on the link, he/she can log into his/her paypal account and make the transaction. Once the transaction was successful a PHP script on my server shall be called that takes as an additional parameter the email-address that was specified in the link described above and identifies the user who just paid.

The paypal documentation is a mess -- and I could not figure out yet how to pass the users' email address in a paypal "buy now button" link. Any help is highly appreciated.

Best!
Sebastian

Comment: Have you looket at some tutorials? I have found for instance http://jdmweb.com/how-to-easily-integrate-a-paypal-checkout-with-php

Comment: Yes, I tried to find. The link that you provide is about a complete web shop, but I just want to have a single customized button, because I have only a single service (access to some member area) that is sold. So I think the "Pay now" button that somehow can be customized would be best. Also, the "button" is not really on my page, but just send to the user and embedded into the email as a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the email from the database , grab the code from paypal , and place your $email variable into the input value.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value='".$email."'> // here the email from DB
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

If you do not want the button just link to  `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=test%40hotmail%2ecom&lc=US&button_subtype=services&currency_code=USD&bn=PP%2dBuyNowBF%3abtn_buynowCC_LG%2egif%3aNonHosted`
where `business=test%40hotmail%2ecom` is the variable you format

Comment: Thanks! But can I avoid to use all this html code and just generate a plain link that I can, e.g., send in a text mail? Essentially, there is no web-page that shows the button, but only an email is sent to the user that contains his/her customized link...

Comment: @user1513073 solutions are never so easy. ;)

Comment: @sircapsalot maybe I can "transform" the above html form into a link.... Is that what you mean?

Comment: @user1513073 I was just being sny.  you could just extract what he put as the link. `<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"><img src="paypalimage" /> $emailAddress</a>`

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to try this and actually the business field is required to be the id of the merchant (so my email addresse). I wanted however to put there the email address of the customer that is taken out of my database and which identifies the payment that was made to a  customer. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: What do you need help with? you know how to query a database in PHP?